# Possible to use SSL/TLS without changing Berkeley socket code?

Tags: c++, ssl, tcp, openssl, tls1.2

We have an existing legacy C++ app which uses TCP via Berkeley C sockets.

We need to continue using Berkeley sockets in our existing environment but for a second, new environment we need to use SSL/TLS.

I've programmed with openssl before but this application code is.... significant, not easy to change.

Is there a way to achieve SSL without making code changes? (networking, proxies etc)

Comment: Yes. You can create a tcp proxy server that will forward your raw requests to your destination with ssl enabled. This can be done on the local machine using a loopback address inside an existing application

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no "make-it-happen" button somewhere that can be pushed in order to enable SSL for a socket, without any other code changes, whatsoever. Either an external proxy, or code changes, are required.

Comment: @Alvov1 thanks, that sounds very interesting. You want to put it as an answer? Can you add as much detail as possible because I know nothing about proxy servers or loopback addresses.

Comment: There's a whole host of new failure modes you need to consider, so a no-code solution will be hard. Specifically, detecting security issues will be impossible, since your existing code by definition can't detect them.

Comment: @MSalters What sort of security issues?

Comment: @ms77: You're using TLS for security reasons, I assume? That's pretty much the entire point of TLS. That means you're supposed to have threat models and the like. I don't know your context, but if there are no possible security issues in your environment then you wouldn't be using TLS I hope

Comment: See [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/) and [ghostunnel](https://github.com/ghostunnel/ghostunnel) for two popular proxy implementations.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your needs. To send HTTP requests, you can implement a proxy server that will redirect all incoming requests to their destination by adding ssl / tls functionality. For this method, most likely it will not be possible to find a solution "out of the box". I would recommend using [Poco](https://docs.pocoproject.org/current/Poco.html), [ServerApplication](https://docs.pocoproject.org/current/Poco.Util.ServerApplication.html), [HTTPs Client session](https://docs.pocoproject.org/current/Poco.Net.HTTPSClientSession.html).

To use protocols that support a permanent connection, it is more logical to set up a secure tunnel, which will add ssl / tls to all incoming packets, and remove it from outgoing packets. For this method it is quite possible to find a solution out of the box. Try using the stunnel / ghostunnel from the recommendations. Also, this option can definitely be implemented using the same Poco library, or using low-level posix sockets and openssl encryption.

Both solutions can be set up on the secondary node by sending packets from the source server to the address of the new node, or on the local machine by sending packets to the loopback address.

Comment: So we can keep our code as it is, change the config to send TCP to another host. On this host setup the SSL tunnel, which will then fufill the SSL requirement?